# Is there a way to share a json file (or blob) for all GMail add-ons in the same GSuite domain?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I currently have a GMail add-on and it is being used by at least 3 different GSuite domains. Currently each instance of that GMail add-on queries our servers for its configuration data via an HTTP-POST request.

However with the influx of new users from different GSuite domains, I am currently researching a way for users within the same domain to share a configuration (JSON) file or blob.

I was wondering if I can use Google Drive for this. The biggest question I have is if there is a "directory" or "url" which i can "hardcode" and make my add-on access (read-only)? Say for example "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/myuniquepath/addon-config.json", where "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/" is hardcoded. "myuniquepath/addon-config.json" is something I will add in my drive though.

If the google drive solution is infeasible, is there a mechanism like the [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#property-managed) API in appscript or GMail Add-ons? Where an admin can set the blob using the admin dashboard and all users within the domain can then just 'pull' those configuration data.

Thank you.

Comment: I think that the domain admin would need to create a shared folder and provide that folder ID to the addon.  And the addon would need to be able to access shared folders.  I think the only way your code can do that is either with Advanced Drive Service or the Drive API and a special setting for `Drive.Files.insert(resource,undefined,{ supportsAllDrives: true });//supportsAllDrives is so that it will work on shared
    //drives`

Comment: @AlanWells Thank you for the quick response. Is there any way, that this ID can be hardcoded? I would really love for the admin to not have to 'set' anything for the addons. So that "it would just work" when installed in the domain, after the admin has prepared the config blob.

Comment: Only the account that published the addon can hardcode something.  Is your code open source?  If your addon code is open source, and each domain is obtaining a copy of your code and publishing the addon themselves, then they could hard code it.  You might be able to use a library in your addon, and then you could edit the library without needing to republish the addon.  But even then, the account that installed the addon can't edit the code and save the project.

Comment: When the addon runs, it runs as if it were running from the account that installed it.  So, the addon can't directly access your Google Drive, and create a folder that is shared with the account that installed the addon.  You'd still need to make an external request using UrlFetchApp.fetch(url) from the addon to an Apps Script project in your account, and then that Apps Script project would need to know where to access the data for a particular domain, and then send data back to the addon.  So, you'd still be making an external request.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try and get the email of the active user, and get the domain. Access the data based on the domain you got.

```
var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var domain = email.split('@').pop();
if(domain == "yahoo.com") {
  //access the data for yahoo.com domains
}
else if(domain == "google.com") {
  //access the data for google.com domains
}
```

#### Note:

- Just make sure that the user from the specific domain has the needed access/permissions when accessing the data for that specific domain.